# Change WordPress URL folder name to another without redirecting

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, permalinks

I'm trying to change my WordPress site's URL (without redirecting) from:
example.com/go/take/
to:
example.com/go/give/

Also, if my wordpress site is located in the /go/ folder, is it possible for me to trim /go/ ?

Thank you.

Comment: You can rename folders in your http directory such as; go, take and give folders. As long as these folders exist in your C:/ drive, all you need to do is to rename the folder from take -> give. You can also move them around from one location to another location.

Answer (score 0):

These are two separate issues.

1. Regarding the first issue, are you saying that you still want a user
   to type in example.com/go/take, but be served the file from
   example.com/go/give without changing the url?  You can install the
   wordpress redirection plugin to do that.  You can create a 'pass
   through' redirect which will do this.
2. Here's what you can do to run example.com from a wordpress install
   in the go subdirectory: 
   http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory